# Jaspersoft Studio: Username may not be null (HTTP proxy issue)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, http-proxy

if you get an error similar to this although your credentials are correct or have even worked before in this environment, it may be due to an HTTP proxy misconfiguration (see answer below)

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Username may not be null
    at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:48)
    at org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials.<init>(UsernamePasswordCredentials.java:78)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.utils.HttpUtils.getCredentials(HttpUtils.java:107)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.utils.HttpUtils.setupProxy(HttpUtils.java:45)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.restv2.RestV2ConnectionJersey.connect(RestV2ConnectionJersey.java:91)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.protocol.ProxyConnection.connect(ProxyConnection.java:61)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.WSClientHelper.checkConnection(WSClientHelper.java:85)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.connect(ServerProfileWizard.java:101)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard.access$1(ServerProfileWizard.java:97)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.server.wizard.ServerProfileWizard$2.run(ServerProfileWizard.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **`Eclipse->Window->Preferences->General->Network Connections`** settings. If your **Jasper server is not behind an HTTP proxy** it must be included and selected (yellow) in the **`Proxy bypass`** section (or no proxy may be necessary at all - but this seems more unlikely because other proxied network services would not be available then within Eclipse).
**Otherwise** it should **not be included therein**.

If you should get another error **`org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found`**
later on it could be an unrelated error due to a **server<->studio version mismatch**, e.g. described here:

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/823765/jaspersoft-studio-551-unable-connect-jasperreports-server-450

(I know this is not directly related to the question, but it may help after such an update scenario (which may be a big waste of time) ...)

**Instead of downgrading Jasper Studio** you can try to **change** the **URL** and Jasper **version** in the **server connection**. Try to **remove `services/repository/` from your URL**, which worked for me :-)
(...as mentioned here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/3497 )